# Powershell unable to get group SID while using remoting via azure pipeline

Tags: windows, azure, powershell, windows-server-2016

I have a script that gets the SID of 2 different groups which works perfectly when I remote in the server and execute code with it's params. My issue is when I use that script with azure pipeline the code failed and give me a error

> unable to connect the server. This may be because this server does not exist, it is currently down,
> or it does not have the Active Directory Web Services running.

I suspect the current server that is running my script does have the proper credentials to access "main.ad.group.com" or "sub.ad.group.com" while using azure pipeline. My script is running on "server A" but needs to communicate with "main.ad.group.com" or "sub.ad.group.com" to get the SID.

**Code**

> ```
>     $groupType = "Main"
>     $group = "Group A"
>     $SID = ""
>
>     if ($groupType -eq "Main")
>     {
>         $SID = Get-ADGroup -server "main.ad.group.com" -Identity $group
>         $SID = $SID.SID.value
>     }
>     elseif ($groupType -eq "Sub")
>     {
>         $SID = Get-ADGroup -server "sub.ad.group.com" -Identity $group
>         $SID = $SID.SID.value
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out

```
 $user = "domain\user"
 $pass = "secret pass"
 $securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $pass -AsPlainText -Force

 $Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $user, $securePassword

 $groupType = "Main"
 $group = "Group A"
 $SID = ""

    if ($groupType -eq "Main")
    {

    $SID = Get-ADGroup -server "main.ad.group.com" -Identity $group -Credential $Credential
    $SID = $SID.SID.value
    }
    elseif ($groupType -eq "Sub")
    {
        $SID = Get-ADGroup -server "sub.ad.group.com" -Identity $group -Credential $Credential
        $SID = $SID.SID.value
    }
```